# WordPress Ajax JSON success return no being recognized

Tags: ajax, wp-mail, json

I'm working on a contact form for a website using an jQuery Ajax call method that then uses WordPress's building in admin-ajax.php to submit the form's values, send them to an email address via wp_mail and then, if successful, send back an array through json_encode. The form works and the email sends but the success data isn't send after and the Ajax :success function doesn't initiate.

This has worked on other sites and I'm not sure why it's not working on this site. It send the email, just my jQuery method gets no success callback.

Here's what I've been using.

jQuery

```
(document).ready(function($){

$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Only alphabetical characters"); 

$.validator.addMethod("phoneNum", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\-\s]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Phone number can only be number and dashes.");


$("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required:true,
           lettersonly: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
        phone: {
            phoneNum: true,
            },
        message:  {
            required:true
        }
        },
     messages: {
            name:  {
                required: "Please enter your name.",
                lettersonly: "Needs to be letters, no numbers please."
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email adress.",
                email: "Please enter your valid email adress."
            },
            phone: {

            },
            message:{
                required: "Please enter a message.",
            }
          },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#contact-msg').html('<p class="ajaxLoader">Sending Email...</p>');

       $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status == 'success') {
                            $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                        }
                        $('#contact-msg').html(response.errmessage);
                    }
                });

    }

});
});
```

Function.php

```
// CONTACT FORM SCRIPTS    
function contactform_add_script() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'contactform-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/contact_me.js', array('jquery') , null, true);
wp_localize_script( 'contactform-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'contactform_add_script');


// CONTACT FORM PROCESSING 
 function ajax_contactform_action_callback() {
$error = '';
$status = 'error';
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $error = 'All fields are required to enter.';

    } else {
        $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $number = filter_var($_POST['phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
       // $treatments = filter_var($_POST['treatments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
        $subject = 'A message from St. Romain Interiors\'s contact form.';
        $message .= PHP_EOL.'Sender\'s name: '.$name;
        $message .= PHP_EOL.'Phone number: '.$number;
        $message .= PHP_EOL.'E-mail address: '.$email;

        $message .= PHP_EOL.'Message: '.stripslashes($_POST['message']);

        $sendmsg = "Thanks for the message! We will respond as soon as possible.";
        $to = 'blah@gmail.com'; // If you like change this email address
        // replace "noreply@yourdomain.com" with your real email address

        $header .= 'Reply-To: '.$email.PHP_EOL;
        if ( wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $header) ) {
            $status = 'success';
            $error = $sendmsg;
        } else {
            $error = 'Some errors occurred.';
        }
    }

$resp = array('status' => $status, 'errmessage' => $error);
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
echo json_encode($resp);
die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_contactform_action', 'ajax_contactform_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contactform_action',      'ajax_contactform_action_callback' );
```

UPDATE!

If I replace the submitHandler with this it returns the sentence, but now the email is never sent...

```
     submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#contact-msg').html('<p class="ajaxLoader">Sending Email...</p>');

        $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: { action: "contactform_action",
                   values: $('#contact-form').serialize() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

                        $('#contact-msg').html('<p>Thanks for the message!</p>');
                    }
                });

    }
```

UPDATE #2

I replaced the success function with the original from the first post, but kept the data values you suggested and it's doing the same old thing, sending the email but not sending a success callback. On Mozilla Firebug I was able to find this information in the Response Headers panel.

```
X-Robots-Tag:   noindex
X-Powered-By:   PHP/5.6.14
x-frame-options:    SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Server: Apache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires:    Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Date:   Mon, 26 Oct 2015 06:13:54 GMT
Content-Type:   application/json
Cache-Control:  no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

UPDATE #3

Here's the response I see in Firebug

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>/home/theski/public_html/stromain/wp-content/themes/stromain
/functions.php</b> on line <b>156</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>/home/theski/public_html/stromain/wp-content/themes/stromain
/functions.php</b> on line <b>157</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: phone in <b>/home/theski/public_html/stromain/wp-content/themes/stromain
/functions.php</b> on line <b>158</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: message in<b>/home/theski/public_html/stromain/wp-content/themes
/stromain/functions.php</b> on line <b>161</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: message in <b>/home/theski/public_html/stromain/wp-content/themes/stromain
/functions.php</b> on line <b>165</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: header in <b>/home/theski/public_html/stromain/wp-content/themes
/stromain/functions.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
{"status":"success","errmessage":"Thanks for the message! We will respond as soon as possible."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer was that debug was set to 'true' in wp_config**. This created error html to be returned by Wordpress because variables in the functions.php were being assigned via ajax but Wordpress debug was reporting them as 'Undefined'. I found this out by viewing the return information on the console tab in Firebug when submitting content on the form. The return was filled with 
 and Undefined errors. This caused the AJAX response to break, not allowing me activate the ajax callback. Setting wp_config debug to 'false' fixed everything.

*At least this is what I'm assuming, please correct me if I'm wrong.*

Comment: Just a note: Fixing the debug errors is probably a better route than just hiding them. It's not difficult to check for a variable before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the action name to your AJAX call. In WordPress, you have to give an action name, the same name you give whatever is after wp_ajax_ and wp_ajax_nopriv_

In this case, the AJAX call should work if you change the data: inside your AJAX call, for this:

```
data: {action: "contactform_action", values: $('#contact-form').serialize()}
```

Then retrieve the values of the form with `$_POST["values"];` in your php function.

Comment: Well I got some good news and some bad news, good news is that the code you suggested worked in that the response function above returns a sentence, bad news is now the email doesn't send...

Comment: And what went wrong????

Comment: I'm not sure how I find that information out, any suggestions?

Comment: I replaced the success function with the original from the first post, but kept the data values you suggested and it's doing the same old thing, sending the email but not sending a success callback. On Mozilla Firebug I was able to find this information that I'm adding to the post above.

Comment: Did you try var_dump in $_POST, but I think $_POST["value"] is a string with the serialized data, not an array. So you have to process it into an array before calling the individual values. Right now I don't remember how to do it in php, but this maight work: http://php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Hey Eduardo, do you mean to try and use unserialized on the return json_encoded array $resp? Do you know how I can incorporate that into the jQuery code?

Comment: I mean before you use $_POST if that is what is causing problems, but I'm not sure of that. You can also send the values of the form fields from jQuery one by one instead of serializing the form, if that's what you want todo.

Comment: Hey Eduardo, thanks for the help, I'll try using var_dump and see if that works. I don't think serializing the $_POST values in the form is the issue. It's passing into my function.php, it's values are being assigned to variables, which are then concatenated and sent via wp_mail(). It's just not returning a confirmation value back to the jQuery Ajax call after executing wp_mail().